# Flutter: How to combine pageview with specific index of bottomnavigation bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I swipe between pageview and the only one index of the bottom navigation bar like Instagram?
My code at mobile_screen_layout.dart – where to combine bottom bar with specific page to pageview:

```
        class MobileScreenLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const MobileScreenLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MobileScreenLayout> createState() => _MobileScreenLayoutState();
}

class _MobileScreenLayoutState extends State<MobileScreenLayout> {
  int _page = 0;
  late PageController pageController; 
  bool isPageFeed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pageController.dispose();
  }

  void onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      _page = page;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var homeItemList = [
      HomeScreen(),
      ChatScreen(),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: homeItemList,
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to swipe left or right to go from HomeScreen to ChatScreen and to HomeScreen?

Comment: I just want to swipe between the first index of bottmbar with another page, not all the indexes of its

Answer (score 0):

You can jump any page with animateToPage or jumpTo, Now your question you can click on bottom navigation item and you can control below code which page you need to show.

```
_pageController.animateToPage(page_index,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.linear);
```